# In Kafka if we have one Consumer and three partition then how consumer consumer message from all partition is parallelly at one time or one by one

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Kafka if we have one Consumer and three partitions in the topic then how consumer can consumer the message parallelly from all partitions at one time or one by one?

I just wanted to know what is consumer strategy in above problem statement

Comment: What specific problem are you running into with this? Is something not working the way you expect?

Answer (score 0):

For the kafka consumer you have the consumer group to decide whether you want to  consume same data by different consumer or distributed within consumers

Now here you have 1 consumer hence only 1 consumer group so it will read 1 by 1 from each partition in round robin fashion

Comment: Thanks your response, my question for 1 consumer and 3 partition will single  consumer consume all partition at time or one by one.

Comment: It will consume one by one in round-robin

Answer (score 0):

Lets take the following scenarios, we have 3 partitions and:

1. 1 consumer
2. 2 consumers
3. 3 consumers
4. 4 consumers

Note, all consumers are using the same consumer group id.

For scenario:

1. The consumer will read all three partitions, round robin across them. Here we have more partitions than consumers.
2. 1 consumer will read to 2 partitions and the other will connect to the remaining partition. Here we have more partitions than consumers.
3. The each of 3 consumers will read 1 partition each, one consumer assigned to one partition. Here we have matched consumer count with partition count, none in excess.
4. The 3 out of the 4 consumers would each read 1 partition each as in the point above, except one consumer would sit idle as it doesn't have a partition to read from.

I hope this answered your question, let me know if you need further details and I'd be happy to help out.

Comment: Thanks your response, my question for 1 consumer and 3 partition will single  consumer consume all partition at time or one by one.

Comment: it'll consume the topics in round robin fashion.